# Image not appearing in Jar file JAVAFX

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2

I have created an application that runs fine but when made into a jar file the image doesn't show. I'm using JAVAFX for the GUI.

**Part of the code**

```
@FXML
private ImageView weatherIconId;
public void setLocation(){
    WeatherToday wT = new WeatherToday();
    File file = new File("src\\weatherIcons\\"+ wT.getIcon() + ".png");
    Image image = new Image(file.toURI().toString());

    try {
        weatherIconId.setImage(image);
        loc.setText(wT.getDescription().substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + wT.getDescription().substring(1) + " " + wT.getCels());

    }catch(Exception e){
        loc.setText("Error News");
    }
}
```

#### Image show in executable

[image: Image show in executable]

#### Image not showing in JAR File

[image: Image not showing in JAR File]

**Full code for class**

```
public class LabelController {

    @FXML
    private TextArea lblN;

    @FXML
    private Label lblTime;

    @FXML
    private Label loc;

    @FXML
    private Label trainUpdate;

    @FXML
    private Label monthDay;

    @FXML
    private Label TFLline;

    @FXML
    private Label BBCL;

    @FXML
    private ImageView weatherIconId;

    static String i;
    static int num;

    public void getAndSetData(){
        setTime();
        setNews();
        setLocation();
        setTrainStatus();
    }

    public void setTime(){
        try {
            LocalTime watch = LocalTime.now();
            DateTimeFormatter shortTime = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedTime(FormatStyle.SHORT);
            i = shortTime.format(watch);

            LocalDate now = LocalDate.now();
            DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMM, dd");
            String formatDate = now.format(formatter);

            System.out.println("After : " + formatDate);

            lblTime.setText(i);
            monthDay.setText(formatDate);

        }catch(Exception e){
            lblTime.setText("Error T");
        }
    }

    public void setNews(){

        BBCL.setTextFill(Color.web("#ff270f"));

        try {
            String news = "";

            for(String n: new News().getHeadLine()){
                news += "- " + n + "\n";
            }

            //Scroll bar in the textArea
            ScrollBar scrollBarv = (ScrollBar)lblN.lookup(".scroll-bar:vertical");
            //Hide scrollbar
            scrollBarv.setDisable(true);
            lblN.setWrapText(true);

            //New information.
            lblN.setText(news);
            lblN.appendText("\n"+ "\n"+ "\n"+ "\n");
            //Automatic scrolling function
            slowScrollToBottom(scrollBarv);
        }catch(Exception e){
            lblN.setText("Error News");
        }
    }

    static void slowScrollToBottom(ScrollBar scrollPane) {
        scrollPane.setValue(1.5);
        Animation animation = new Timeline(
                new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(7),
                        new KeyValue(scrollPane.valueProperty(), 0)));
        animation.play();
    }

    public void setLocation(){
        WeatherToday wT = new WeatherToday();
        File file = new File("src\\weatherIcons\\"+ wT.getIcon() + ".png");
        Image image = new Image(file.toURI().toString());

        try {
            weatherIconId.setImage(image);
            loc.setText(wT.getDescription().substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + wT.getDescription().substring(1) + " " + wT.getCels());

        }catch(Exception e){
            loc.setText("Error News");
        }
    }

    public void setTrainStatus(){

        TFLStatus tS = new TFLStatus();
        LocateMyCity lo = new LocateMyCity();

        int sizeOfService = tS.getTFL().size();
        int countGS = 0;

        if(lo.getmyCityLocation().equalsIgnoreCase("London")) {

            try {

                for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : tS.getTFL().entrySet()) {
                    //Line NOT equal to Good Service - Delay lines
                    if (!entry.getValue().equalsIgnoreCase("Good Service")) {
                        TFLline.setFont(new Font("Arial", 30));
                        TFLline.setStyle("-fx-font-weight: bold");
                        TFLline.setTextFill(Color.web("#ff270f"));
                        TFLline.setText("Services delays:");

                        trainUpdate.setFont(new Font("Arial", 32));
                        trainUpdate.setStyle("-fx-font-weight: bold");
                        trainUpdate.setTextFill(Color.web("#ffffff"));
                        trainUpdate.setText(entry.getKey() + ": " + entry.getValue() + "\n");
                        System.out.println("Name of Service: " + entry.getKey() + " " + entry.getValue() + "\n");
                        ++countGS;

                    }
                }

                if (countGS == 0) {
                    TFLline.setFont(new Font("Arial", 35));
                    TFLline.setStyle("-fx-font-weight: bold");
                    TFLline.setTextFill(Color.web("#25d039"));
                    TFLline.setText("Good Services: Underground & DLR");
                }
                System.out.println(countGS);
                //tS.getTFL().forEach((k,v)-> System.out.println(v));
            } catch (Exception e) {
                loc.setText("Error News");
            }
        }else{
            TFLline.setText(lo.getmyCityLocation());
        }
    }


    @FXML
    public void initialize() {

        Timeline timeline = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(
                Duration.millis(8000),
                ae -> getAndSetData()));
        timeline.setCycleCount(Animation.INDEFINITE);
        timeline.play();



    //   getAndSetTheCurrentTime();
    //       lblN.textProperty().bind(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: If you have some set of images used by the app, include these resources in the jar file and use a `Class`/classloader get the url of the resource. Probably the image is not located at the path `src\\weatherIcons\\whatever.png` relative to the working directory.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this to laod the image

```
  private Image image1 = 
        new Image(this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/src/weatherIcons/image1.png"));
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, change image patches from `"src/image.jpg"` to "`/image.jpg"` and load image with help of classloader `getClass().gerResource("/image.jpg")` because after building jar and move it to somewhere it does not able to see **src** folder and your images does not shown. If it does not work check presence of images in your jar (open it with winRar or 7z file managers) and see in classpath (folder with class files) they must be there.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced this issue once, and I solved like this way:

I made a *img* folder that consists of images. I gave the path of image to button or label etc like this way. 
Now I follow this directory structure to attach images.
[image: Directory Structure]

```
buttonORLabel.setGraphic(new ImageView(new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/image.jpg"))));
```