# new Image instance using (getClass().getResourceAsStream("Path/to/pic")) vs ("Path/to/pic")

Tags: java, imageview, treeview, javafx-8

when I was following a tutorial of javafx and trying to create a new Image instance for an ImageView, to use it for TreeView, I noticed that the tutor used to create an ImageView:
`new ImageView(new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/Path/to/pic"))`

instead of:

`new ImageView(new Image("/Path/to/pic"))`

I tried both, and it works fine for both, I want to know if this rolling around using `getClass().getResourceAsStream()` has any effect or meaning.

Comment: The `getResource` method is for when you deploy your app as a Jar file.  `getResource` searches within the Jar file.  Whereas the path method needs to know where the Jar file is located on disc, which might be difficult to manage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. This is actually very important.

An image is a *resource*. A resource is some unchanging information which is used by the program, such as images, sounds, default properties, templates, initial data etc.

While you are developing, using an IDE, the resources are usually stored as files in a folder in your workspace. So as long as you are using the IDE and not packaging the program, you can get away with treating the resources as files.

But when you want to deploy your program (package it and install it somewhere else, like a server, or somebody else's computer), it is usually packaged into one or more JAR files. The JAR files include the compiled classes and the resources.

When they are inside a JAR file, the resources are no longer files. They are just zip entries (zip entries are not files - they are parts of a zip file which are accessible by using the appropriate software).

If you used file operations to access the resource, you'll run into a problem, like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44553620/4125191). The image will not show - because the file is not there. The resource is not a file, it doesn't exist as a file on the disk. It is just a group of bytes within your JAR file.

To be able to access the resource, you use the class object and `getResourceAsStream()` as you were shown. This "magically" knows (when the class loader and class path are set up correctly) that when you run inside the IDE the resource is stored in a file in the workspace, and when you run from a JAR, the resource is stored inside the JAR. It will get those bytes from where they are stored and you'll be able to create your image.